# RGoogleAnalytics Segment not Agreeing with GA Web Output

Tags: r, google-analytics

Using R and the 'RGoogleAnalytics' package I have run into an issue of when running a query and the query in R not lining up with the table I get with the same segment in the Google Analytics report.  I am using Google's Query Explorer to obtain the segment 'gaid', but I have also tried using the segment definition that the query explorer provides.

```
query.list <- Init(
    start.date = "2015-5-1",
    end.date = "2015-5-31",
    dimensions = "ga:date",
    metrics = "ga:users,ga:sessions", 
    segments = "gaid::...", 
    max.results = 10000,
    sort = "ga:date",
    table.id = "...")

ga.query<- QueryBuilder(query.list)
ga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query,oauth_token,
                                  split_daywise = T)
```

The code runs, gives me a data frame, but the data frame does not match up with the tables I have with the same segment definitions in Google Analytics interface.

The segment of interest excludes specific users (defined by a custom user dimension), and has several session restrictions.  The R code is is including extra users and sessions for some reason.

I've looked into the data trying to find out what users and sessions are getting through, but I am not finding any consistent trends between what is getting by the filter.  Is anyone else running into this issue?  Any suggestions?

Comment: How different are they? The GA interface shows sampled data, and I believe the API shows less sampled (more accurate) data. If they're only off by a few % then you should be good. At the very least, I wouldn't expect these 2 sources to match number-for-number.

Comment: The R output and the GA interface agree about 90% of the time and are off by about 5% when they disagree.  R's output can be considered more accurate then?

Comment: Yes, I'd trust the data you're getting from the API more than the data within the interface (GA website). Here's more info, https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en

Comment: I agree with that for 100% R data is the accurate one